# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion errors?

Tags: c, pointers

For some reason, I'm getting an error at this line:

```
while ((en = strtok(NULL, " " ) !=NULL)){ //do something }
```

and at this line (the error for this one is 'comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'void *'), even though inputString is a char array and null is null.

```
while (!inputString[i]==NULL)
```

en is a char, and was declared as char *en. I'm not sure why...is it because I can't compare them with NULL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem isn't the comparison - it's the assignment.  `!=` has higher precedence than `=`, so your expression is parsed as:

```
en = (strtok(NULL, "") != NULL)
```

presumably `en` is a pointer type, and the result of `!=` is an `int`, so that's where the warning arises.  You probably meant:

```
(en = strtok(NULL, "")) != NULL
```

as the condition.  The same is true in your second example - `!` has higher precedence than `==`, so you're comparing the result of `!inputString[i]` (which has type `int`) to `NULL` (which may have type `void *`).  You might have meant:

```
while (!(inputString[i] == NULL))
```

which can also be written as:

```
while (inputString[i] != NULL)
```

or just

```
while (inputString[i])
```